# Setting static events to null using reflection

Tags: c#, .net, events, reflection, static

I have the following problem:

I got a class with ~100 static events and i want to set all those events to null (removing all delegates) when Disposing.
Can I do this using reflection? because otherwise it would be a lot to write and hard to keep in sync with changes.

I tried something like this:

```
foreach (EventInfo eventInfo in GetType().GetEvents(BindingFlags.Static | BindingFlags.Public))
     {
        // ?
     }
```

but i dont know how to set them null. I guess this is not workong with reflection, is their maybee another easy way?

Br,
David

Comment: I don't understand. Why should disposing of an instance null all static events?

Comment: Are these events automatically-implemented?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The following ought to work:

```
   foreach (EventInfo eventInfo in GetType().GetEvents(BindingFlags.Static | BindingFlags.Public))
   {
      FieldInfo field = GetType().GetField(eventInfo.Name, BindingFlags.Static | BindingFlags.NonPublic);
      field.SetValue(null, null);             
   }
```

Provided that there *are* indeed backing fields for the events of course, otherwise there is no way to "set" them.

Answer (score 1):

You can't "set" events, the only available operations are to add or remove a specific delegate.

You can set the backing field however.  Note that there's not necessarily a 1:1 correspondence between events and fields -- WinForms uses a dictionary of delegates to avoid wasting space for events with no handlers.